# SQL Query -filtering for new record while querying

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have the following table,say subscription which contains these records

```
app_id  Status  Date
1   Submitted   d1
1   Open        d2
1   Approved    d3
2   Submitted   d4
2   Submitted   d5(d4<d5)
3   Open        d6
3   Approved    d7
4   Open        d8
4   Declined    d9
```

My Output Logic is:

1) For each app_id, we need to pick the date where Status is Submitted.

2) In case if there is 2 records with status as Submitted for the app_id,we need to pick the record which has earliest submitted date.

3) If there is no Submitted date,then take the date which have "Approved" or "Declined" Status.

My Output for the above table should look like this

```
 app_id   date
   1       d1
   2       d4
   3       d7
   4       d9
```

Can you please let me know how to write sql query for the same?

Comment: Is it possible to have both `Approved` and `Declined` records for the same `app_id`?  Or multiple `Approved` or `Declined` records?  Is it possible to have no `Submitted` record ***and*** no `Approved` or `Declined` records?

Comment: Hi Mat,It'll be either approved or Declined for an app_id.No,an app_id should have either one of the status- Submitted/Approved/Declined records.There is no multiple records for Approved/Declined but can have multiple records for Submitted status.

Comment: The OP has stated, in the comments to my answer, that they are not actually using SQL Server  (I've since removed the tag). I have asked them to update their post accordingly, and tag correctly.

Comment: What version of Hive?

Comment: Hive 2.0 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
select app_id, min(thedate) 
from #tryout
where (
        thestatus='Submitted'  OR (thestatus = 'Approved' or thestatus='Declined')
      )
group by app_id
```

Comment: This won't work if something has a `[status]` other than `'submitted'` for a `[date]` prior to that. Also, for the SAmple data, your `WHERE` clause doesn't filter anything.  Having an `OR` for every value is redundant.

Comment: I tried with the sample data provided and it is giving same output though. If anything has status other than 'Submitted' which falls on earlier date then that will get filtered out by where cluase.

Comment: Correct, it will. but the OP hasn't provided any examples where the item was first Open and then submitted (only missing Submitted).

Comment: I tried with such entry by adding app_id 5 with first entry 'Open' and then 'Submitted'. The query resulted in 5, <date of Submitted>. Not sure if that is what's expected by him.

Comment: I think this query works assuming Submitted status if present should be earliest date,which i think so.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I actually misread and didn't notice the extra parenthesis, my apologies. If you edit your post (perhaps add a terminator (`;`) to it), I'll be happy to upvote it.

Comment: *Thumbs up!* :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the sample data that has since been removed (why...)?

```
CREATE TABLE #Record (App_id int,
                      [Status] varchar(12),
                      [date] char(2));

INSERT INTO #Record
VALUES (1,'Submitted','d1'),
       (1,'Open     ','d2'),
       (1,'Approved ','d3'),
       (2,'Submitted','d4'),
       (2,'Submitted','d5'),
       (3,'Open     ','d6'),
       (3,'Approved ','d7'),
       (4,'Open     ','d8'),
       (4,'Declined ','d9');
GO

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY App_Id
                              ORDER BY CASE [Status] WHEN 'Submitted' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, [date] ASC) AS RN
    FROM #Record)
SELECT App_id,
       [Status],
       [date]
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;

GO
DROP TABLE #Record;
```

Comment: I want to exceute the query in hive..Getting error - cannot recognize input near 'CASE' '

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the above T-SQL I've provided, which means you've changed something. Not really sure what you mean by "in hive".

Comment: Also, @vasanth ,just noticed that that doesn't look like a SQL Server error. Are you actually using SQL Server?

Comment: No, i try to use this query in Hive (Bigdata) Query Language,which is similar to sql. I haven't use sql-server.I need a simple sql which filter the above criteria.

Comment: Then why have you tagged SQL Server..? Please edit your question and tag correctly.

Comment: This may work in Hive just without the square brackets.  Though I'm note sure how it will behave with a column named `date`.  I believe there is also an option to enable quoted identifiers and use back-ticks, though that causes confusion due to how they're used for regular expressions.  *(I'm a Hive novice, sorry)*

Comment: I've got no experience with Hive I'm afraid, so I have no idea how to even begin converting it to be able to be used in it. It could, as @MatBailie suggest, be quite simple, but i woulnd't like to have a go, due to the fact that I have no idea how (dis)similar the syntax is.